# Can a micro service (in Spring-boot 1.x) hit a REST endpoint of another micro service(in spring-boot 2.x) when using Feign?

Tags: spring-boot

We have few micro services on spring-boot 1.x and we are trying to upgrade them to spring-boot 2.x.

As part of this upgrade, we converted few micro services into spring-boot 2.x and some of them are still on spring-boot 1.x. Now my question is, if a micro service is using Feign to invoke/call a REST endpoint of another micro service, should we have both the micro services on same spring-boot version or can they still communicate with being on two different versions?